# Question regarding galois/ring theory.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, galois-theory

Given $K:Q$ a normal extension, $G$ the galois group of that, and $H$ a subgroup of $G$, let $a \in K$. Set $b = \sum{\sigma_i(a)}$ for all  $\sigma_i$ $\in H$. Both $H$ and $G$ are finite.

a. Show $\sigma(b)$ = $b$ for all $\sigma \in H$.

b. Show that $H\subseteq Q(b)$.

c. Deduce the upper bound for [$Q(b):Q$].

For a, here is my attempt:
Because $b = \sigma_1(a)+\sigma_2(a)+...\sigma_n(a)$, and $\sigma_i(\sigma_j(a)$ is in H (it's a subgroup), doing $\sigma_i(b)$ for arbitrary $\sigma \in H$, will just end up reordering the summation that represents $b$, which will not change the result so $\sigma_i(b) = b$ for all $\sigma \in H$.

As for part b, I'm not sure what $Q(b)$ means. Is that just the ring extension with basis:

{ $\alpha, \beta(\sum{\sigma(a)}$ }, for $\alpha,\beta \in Q$. How would $H$, a subgroup representing automorphisms, be a subset of a ring?

As for part c, I feel once I understand $Q(b)$ and part b, I might be able to figure this one out myself, hopefully.

Comment: Ring or field?$Q(b)$ is a field extension. $Q(b) \supset H$ doesn't make sense, you are right.

Comment: Ok I'm going to just skip part b now then. Does my proof for part a make sense? Also, how would I attempt part C. My guess would just be that $|Q(b):Q|$ = $|H|$ as an upper bound.

Comment: You should be able to convince yourself if your work for $a$ is correct or not. If you have doubts, write out your logic more clearly. :) $Q(b)$ is invariant under $H$. So $Q(b) \subset K^H$. What is $[K^H : K]$?

Comment: In fact I think $b$ is probably supposed to be $K^H \supset Q$?

Comment: Wait I forget what that notation means. What does $K^{H}$ mean again. I can't find it in my notes (messy notes).

Comment: Subfield of $H$ invariants.

Comment: I can't quite follow the discussion, because I think there are errors in your notations.

(a) Your argument that $b$ is fixed by $H$ is quite correct

(b) It shows that $\mathbf Q(b) \subset K^H$. Notations: $\mathbf Q(b)$ is the subfield of $K$ generated by $b$, i.e. the smallest subfield of $K$ containing $b$. And $K^H$ is the subfield of $K$ fixed (elementwise) by $H$

(c) Then clearly $[\mathbf Q(b):\mathbf Q] \le [K^H : \mathbf Q]